# Do all systems in z domain are filters?

Tags: filters, z-transform

Normally a system transfer function is represented by H(z)

I want to know wether all those system transfer functions are only representing a digital filter?

Or their any other thing/entity in z domain that can be represented by H(z)

Comment: That depends on your definition of "digital filter"; for me, the definition of digital filter is pretty much "a system that implements a z-Domain transfer function", so for me, these two are pretty much equivalent. If **your** definition of filter is something else, for example "any system that shows deterministic frequency-selective behaviour", then, no, the things that you can represent as a transfer function also cover non-selective systems.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about this:

Everything that can be represented as a rational function in the Z-domain can also be represented as a linear difference equation in the time domain. As such at can be interpreted (and implemented) as a filter. It may be non-causal or unstable, but it's still a filter.

You can certainly represent things in the z-Domain that are NOT rational functions, however, that would be a system transfer function anymore, because the transfer function is only defined for LTI (Linear Time Invariant) Systems

Comment: Transfer function  cannot be defined for non-Lti systems??

Comment: that is correct, Man.

Comment: Non causal and unstable filters are realizable?

Comment: Man, re-read Hilmar's answer. He **specifically** addressed that.